# Problem of dragging links into emacs

Tags: org-mode

I want to use `org-ref` and `org-download` which provide convenient methods drag links into emacs to download the pdf file or image file. But following the config of the readmes, I still can not get both work. When I drag a url into emacs, it just insert a url of current buffer. I wonder whether this is a issue of specific version of emacs. I'm using the `emacs-mac` installed by `brew`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.s. I can find either a `org-ref` tag or `org-download` tag, so I tagged this as `org-mode`, sorry.

Comment: It must be an issue with emacs-mac and either how it is built, or related to the changes made to support osx. If you use "brew install emacs", it works for me.